# slam_gmapping installation

Tags: ros, navigation, installation, catkin-package, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am doing the tutorial [How to Build a Map Using Logged Data](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData) which  requires the use of gmapping. Well, I do not know how to install it. I found an installation option via **apt-get** but I would like to install from the git repository. The gmapping ROS package is called [slam_gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping) and from its web page the git repository address available is https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git.

Someone can give me instructions on how to install slam_gmapping package via clonning the its repository?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224502/slam_gmapping-installation/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all: do you mean "install" that the end result should be the same as as with `apt-get`? I.e. `slam_gmapping` is installed in `/opt/ros`? Then I would go for the `apt-get` version, even though it is possible with catkin directly.

If you "just" want to have it in you workspace, I'd suggest you go through the [catkin Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials) so that you understand what actually happens.
In short, the required steps are:

1. create a catkin workspace:

   ```
    mkdir -p catkin_ws/src
    cd catkin_ws/src
    source /opt/ros/<DISTRO>/setup.bash
    catkin_init_workspace
   ```
2. clone the repository:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git
   ```
3. compile the workspace

   ```
    cd ..
    catkin_make
   ```
4. source the workspace

   ```
    source devel/setup.bash
   ```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oakafka](https://answers.ros.org/users/26997/oakafka/) on 2016-05-28**:
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "openslam_gmapping"
with any of the following names:
openslam_gmappingConfig.cmake
openslam_gmapping-config.cmake
I got this error after doing catkin_make following your commands. How can I fix this problem
thanks a lot

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-04**:
You also Need to satisfy all dependencies. You can do that by either also cloning all relevant repositories (`openslam_gmapping` can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_gmapping)) or by installing the provided binaries (`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-openslam-gmapping`). ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-04**:
I'd highly recommend to use the `apt-get` Approach here, because `openslam_gmapping` does not fit easily into the ROS Workspace layout (afair), and would really overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt install ros-kinetic-gmapping Substitute whatever ROS distro you have if its not kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [griz11@twc.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/26973/griz11@twc.com/) with karma: 21 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2